# How to reset Vuetify form but still keep v-select selected?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a simple Vuetify form with two v-text-fields and one v-select, the v-select is a dropdown of values one of which is to be selected.

After I submit the form I clear the form by calling `this.$refs.myForm.reset()`. It does clear my form except it also clears the v-select and makes it not selected with any value.

The v-select has a `v-model="selectedMenuId"`, and I tried to manually set the `selectedMenuId` value after the form reset but that's not working.

So how do you clear the text fields but leave the v-select still selected?

---

Thanks to an answer below, I should mention I tried to set my two text fields v-model vars to empty string. Doing so triggers my form validation, so the fields do become empty but they are also in red and with error messages saying they are required. So alternatively is there a way to do this without triggering the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `this.$refs.myForm.reset()` you can manually set the v-model variables of the two textfields to an empty string. This way the text fields will be empty but the select list will not be changed.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried and I should have mentioned this above, but by setting those text fields to empty string triggers the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Manually set the variables to empty string and then call `resetValidaion()` on the form ref to reset the validation state.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the exact same problem as you. I managed to solve it in a way that worked for me:

Instead of using `this.$refs.form.reset()` to reset the fields, I first assigned empty string values to the v-models and then called `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()` to clear the hints of validation. For me it worked as expected!

EDIT: I call `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()` to remove the validation triggers AFTER clearing the fields with empty strings.

Comment: Isn't this the same guidance as offered in [@sadra.barik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554486/3025856) from over a year ago? If not, can you [edit] you clarify the distinction?

Comment: You are right! I looked more closely at the answers and noticed that I messed up and mixed the two previous answers lol. But I will keep my answer with the edit as I believe it clarifies the procedure.